# Do I have to delete/add attachment when I change the file before sending the e-mail?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2013, attachments

When I edit the content of file (e.g. excel worksheet) that I have already attached to a not yet sent e-mail message in Outlook, I usually delete the attachment and attach the same file to the same e-mail anew. But I am wondering if this is necessary?

When the file content is added to the e-mail message in Outlook: when I attach it or when I send the message?

Is there any way how to make Outlook behave so that I do not need to re-attach changed file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test this easily enough. The problem with your question is it may go out of date and you don't state which version of outlook. However, if you do the following test, you'll know for sure regardless of version (and program).

1. Create a text file with some content.
2. Attach it to an email.
3. Open the file from the disc location and change the content, making it clear this is new content in case you forget which is which..
4. Click the send button
5. Now, assuming you send to yourself, you should receive an email.
6. Open the attached file.
7. Review the content. At this point you should know which it is!

Repeat the process above but instead of changing the contents of the file on the disc, open the file from the email program and change it there.

Comment: The only way to avoid re-attaching seems to be doubleclick embedded attachment and edit it - but it will not update content of the original file.

Answer (score 2):

If you attach a file to Outlook to an email you have not sent yet, and you edit that file - you will need to remove the attachment and add it again.

The changes will not apply once you make the edit and press save on the document (e.g. Word or Excel).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to remove and re-add the attachment after changing the original.  Email clients typically make a copy of the attachment prior to sending, so the one attached is an old representation of the original file.  With web based email like gmail et. al. the attachment is physically uploaded to their servers, so, if using a web based interface, the answer is still a very obvious YES.